# Why does "which" miss commands even when the /bin directory is in PATH?

Tags: perl, csh

## Background

I am currently testing a perl script, running in cshell ([company default if you were wondering](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)) that will be used by a Jenkins job. As part of that script, I am doing a sanity check that gradle exists in the path.

I am adding the gradle directory to the path, then I save a local version of the path as seen below:

```
$ENV{PATH} .= ":/vobs/common/gradle-X.X/bin";
my $myPATH = $ENV{ "PATH" };
```

Then I do the sanity check with the [which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command inside a [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command as depicted below:

```
system ("/bin/env PATH=$myPath which gradle" );
```

The error returned states that I added the path correctly, but for some reason it cannot find gradle within it as seen below:

```
which: no gradle in (<standard directories>:/vobs/common/gradle-X.X/bin)
```

---

**Note:** Another main reason I mentioned cshell is that these two questions **don't** apply to my issue because they are bash related:

[Why 'whereis' and 'which' don't show me location of command?](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

[How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

## Question

Why does "which" miss commands despite knowing that the /bin directory exists in the path?

Comment: Does it work when you type this command yourself? Your script might not have enough permissions to access `/vobs/common/gradle-X.X/bin`

Comment: That's it, when I run `/bin/env $path which gradle` in command line, it returns `/bin/env: /home/adm/common/binOverrides: Permission denied.`

Comment: You should probably post that as an actual answer, so it can be upvoted/accepted. @UjinT34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script might not have enough permissions to access `/vobs/common/gradle-X.X/bin`.